# filtering pandas dataframe and avoid nan

Tags: python, pandas

Ok I have this pandas dataframe

```
import pandas
dfp=pandas.DataFrame([5,10,1,7,13,4,5,7,8,10,11,3])
```

And i want to create a second data frame with the rows that have a value greater than 5, thereby:

```
dfp2=dfp[dfp>5]
```

My problem is that I obtain this result:

```
    0
0   NaN
1   10
2   NaN
3   7
4   13
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   7
8   8
9   10
10  11
11  NaN
```

And what I want is this other result:

```
    0
0   10
1   7
2   13
3   7
4   8
5   10
6   11
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You're using the mask generated from the comparison so where it's `False` it returns `NaN`, to get rid of those call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna):

```
In [32]:
dfp[dfp > 5].dropna()

Out[32]:
     0
1   10
3    7
4   13
7    7
8    8
9   10
10  11
```

The mask here:

```
In [33]:
dfp > 5

Out[33]:
        0
0   False
1    True
2   False
3    True
4    True
5   False
6   False
7    True
8    True
9    True
10   True
11  False
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!! My problem now is that i have several columns in my dataframe and when I do this df3=df2[df2.country=='BE'].dropna() the na rows are not removed. how could I deal with it? Thanks a lot!! What I mean is that the indexes are not restarted

Comment: The indexing references the original df as it's a view, you can reset it: `dfp[dfp > 5].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)`